# Used Microsoft Office to create list of select options, single quote pasting to eclipse no recognized

Tags: php, eclipse, ms-word

I made a list of hundreds of select options with Office's Word. I used Word for its Find/Replace wildcards. I had the list of countries in a non-friendly php format.

```
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(‘Myanmar‘,’Myanmar’);
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(‘Mongolia‘,’Mongolia’);
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option(‘Nepal‘,’Nepal’);
```

The problem is when I paste it into Eclipse, my PHP file does not recognize them as single quotes in blue. Why, how do you fix this?

It should be like this:

```
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('AL','AL');
    selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('AK','AK');
```

Comment: Don't use office to write code.

Comment: do **NOT** use Word to edit code. It is NOT a code editor, and Word's artificial stupidity will do its utmost to make your life a living hell. Use a real code editor. heck, use edlin... even edlin does a better job of editing code than Word ever will.

Comment: Haha, do you have another way to Find/Replace a thousand lines of code?

Comment: @DDDD: You can't find Find/Replace in Eclipse?

Comment: Most real code editors or IDEs will happily Find/Replace a thousand lines. Most of them will even use less memory in the process of doing it than Word uses when idle.

Comment: I will use Eclipse next time, I am already experienced with Words wildcards. Any solutions?

Comment: or you could use php itself to do it.

Comment: there's a word setting for turning of its 'smart' quotes.

Comment: @Dagon: I will turn of smart quotes as well. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably way off the mark on this one, but from what you said it sounds like eclipse is having an issue with MS Word's use of smart quotes.  MS Word by default when you type the ' button does not put in a standard single quote but a smart quote, or whatever the heck silly name they call their curved quote mark that they think is so much more appealing visually...  So, you should be able to do a find and replace in your word doc replacing

```
‘
```

with

```
'
```

Then, if it's still giving issues, save to a txt file or some such as that (not *.doc) and open that in note pad, notepad++, etc... and copy-paste from there into eclipse.

Comment: I had to use notepad++ it replaced single qoutes effectively. Thanks!